# When a value in a dataframe's column is x, count how many times another columns value is y using Jupyter Notebooks & Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to be able to answer the question 'How likely is a batsman to be dismissed the following ball after hitting a 6?'.

To do this, I want to evaluate the 'batsman_runs' column for the value '6', and if so, I then want to evaluate the 'player_dismissed' column on the next row down.

E.g. for the entire dataset, if 'batsman_runs' in row 2 = '6', does 'player_dismissed' in row 3 contain a value? If so, count 1.

Here is the structure of my data set shown with the first 5 rows:

```
match_id  inning         batting_team                 bowling_team  over  \
0         1       1  Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore     1   
1         1       1  Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore     1   
2         1       1  Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore     1   
3         1       1  Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore     1   
4         1       1  Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore     1   


   ball    batsman non_striker    bowler  is_super_over   ...    bye_runs  \
0     1  DA Warner    S Dhawan  TS Mills              0   ...           0   
1     2  DA Warner    S Dhawan  TS Mills              0   ...           0   
2     3  DA Warner    S Dhawan  TS Mills              0   ...           0   
3     4  DA Warner    S Dhawan  TS Mills              0   ...           0   
4     5  DA Warner    S Dhawan  TS Mills              0   ...           0   


   legbye_runs  noball_runs  penalty_runs  batsman_runs  extra_runs  \
0            0            0             0             0           0   
1            0            0             0             0           0   
2            0            0             0             4           0   
3            0            0             0             0           0   
4            0            0             0             0           2   


   total_runs  player_dismissed dismissal_kind fielder  
0           0                No           None    None  
1           0                No           None    None  
2           4                No           None    None  
3           0                No           None    None  
4           2                No           None    None  

[5 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: can you give a snippet of the data?

Comment: Create a Minimal and Reproducible example. Don't post data as images. What have you done until now and whats stopping you from getting the result? Your logic seems ok.

Comment: @peili yes I'll get that and add it to the original post, thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use shift function and check for the condition like below. This will give the rows when player is dismissed after 6

```py
df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift()=='6')& (df['player_dismissed']!='')]

## OR, if player_dismissed for not dismissed is null

df[(df['batsman_runs'].shift()=='6')& (~df['player_dismissed'].isnull())]
```

Comment: thank you for considering this - however I get an invalid type comparison error for both of these lines. Kindly would you suggest why this might be?

Comment: what is datatype of your df['batsman_runs'] cloumn, if its integer use 6 instead of '6'

Comment: did the solution worked for you, if yes please upvote and/or mark the answer resolved